# Angular <a> tags are printed twice in ng-switch

Tags: angular

I am using Angular and I have to make a switch on iterate collection.
Unfortunetally following code print always both `<a>` tags.

```
<li *ngFor="let element of account.collection" >
    <div [ngSwitch]=element.anyValue>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="A" [routerLink]="['../A', element.id ]"><span>One</span></a>
        <a *ngSwitchCase="B" [routerLink]="['../B', element.id ]"><span>Two</span></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

any ideas?

Comment: That's not actually using `ngSwitch`, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch for the correct syntax.

Comment: I changed ng-switch-when -> *ngSwitchCase, and ng-switch on -> *ngSwitchCase. Now neither is printed...

Comment: Why did you change `ng-switch` to `*ngSwitchCase`? Give a [mcve] of the update. You should *actually read the docs*, guessing the syntax probably isn't going to be terribly productive.

Comment: Following code was update with @jonrsharpe advices.

Comment: It's not really my advice, so much the actual syntax of the framework you're trying to use.

Comment: Ok, so any idea? Maybe ng-if? I don't understand why it is not working... if I print element.anyValue it is alwaysOne or Two

Comment: ...[edit] the question.

Comment: It was corrected, but still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

ng-if helps in this case. I changed this and now working well.